# dynamically creating an associative array

Tags: javascript, node.js, associative-array

I'm looking to take a hash, create a deep series of keys and then append another hash to the end.

given...

```
var hash_a = {'foo': 'bar'}
var hash_b = {'alpha': 'beta'}
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

how can I generate the following?

```
{
  'foo': 'bar',
  'a':{
    'b':{
      'c': {
        'alpha': 'beta'
       }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't just ask how to do something, show what you've tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var hash_a = {'foo': 'bar'};
var hash_b = {'alha': 'beta'};
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function build(a,b,c){
    var o=c.reduceRight(function(o, n){ var b={}; b[n]=o; return b; }, b);
    for(x in a){ o[x]=a[x]; }
    return o;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8mmfpxw/2/) to play with.
See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) for further explanation of `Array.prototype.reduceRight()`.

Comment: This is close but still not quite right. In the context of the second line of the function, b is being appended to the hash, not as a hash but as an [Object]

Comment: What is the difference to your object? Look at http://jsfiddle.net/a8mmfpxw/3/ used alert, because typing on pad

Comment: I'm afraid that, at my current understanding of js (not much!), I can't answer that question. Perhaps this will help https://gist.github.com/adamwong246/2d732c3537f4774334f6

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. This was a fundamental misunderstanding of how js works. It wasn't until I used the `JSON.stringify` that I realized that the `[Object]` *was* a hash, it was just not being evaluated.